# TikZ: rectangle node with arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the best way to create a node like this?

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[align=left,draw, minimum width=44mm, minimum height=30mm]{
Here \\ the \\ text...};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,arrow box, arrow box arrows={east:0.5cm},align=center] at (0,0) {Text\\text}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]